# How to prevent nested elements from wrapping without specifying widths

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble keeping two nested inline-blocks aligned without specifying widths.  I can get the behavior I want using tables but would prefer to use simpler markup.  Here's the basic markup:

```
<div class="error">
  <i></i>
  <div class="message">Ruh oh</div>
</div>
```

Here is the basic css:

```
.error {
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 8px 10px;
}

i {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.message {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here are the requirements:

- .error can be any width (usually 100%)
- i will be fixed width (usually 45px)
- .message will fill the remaining width of the parent .error
- both i and .message will be vertically aligned in the middle
- .message cannot wrap under i
- no javascript

Here is a fiddle showing a good line (short error), a bad line (longer error messages wrap below the i) and a working example with tables (but I don't want tables).  Please enlighten me!

http://jsfiddle.net/3m2db1hw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `display:table` to parent Div and `display:table-cell` to children i.e. `<i> and <div>`

```
.error {
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    display:table;
}

i {
    width: 45px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell !important;
}

.message {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

here is edited jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/3m2db1hw/1/